# How to create Dropdown animation in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to animate a dropdown symbol to rotate down (when the dropdown option is open) and revert back to it's original position (when dropdown option closes). Please find this attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZaSg.png).

Here's my py file:

```
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as hex
from kivy.animation import Animation

Builder.load_file("dropdowns_and_btns.kv")

kv = """
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition(duration=0)
    IntroPage:
    LandingPage:
    ResultPage:

<IntroPage>
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: hex("#07074D")

        MDLabel:
            text: "BGF"
            color: hex("#ECE4F5")
            font_size: 36
            pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.7)}
            halign: "center"

        RoundedGradientButton:
            text: "START"
            font_size: 20
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.08
            pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.3)}
            on_release: app.root.current = "landing_page"

<LandingPage>
    name: "landing_page"
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: hex("#07074D")

        MDLabel:
            icon_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
            text: "Please select"
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.9}
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 32
            color: hex("#ECE4F5")
                                                                                # Dropdown Label
        MDFloatLayout:
            size_hint: 0.75, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.5)}

            BoxLayout
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.9
                pos_hint: {"center": (0.26, 0.9)}
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Month"
                    color: hex("#ECE4F5")

            BoxLayout
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.9
                pos_hint: {"center": (0.79, 0.9)}
                MDLabel:
                    text: "Year"
                    color: hex("#ECE4F5")
                                                                            # Dropdown Button
            MDGridLayout:
                cols: 2
                size_hint: 1, 0.3
                pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.65)}
                spacing: 30

                DropdownMenu:
                    id: month
                    text: 'Select'
                    values: [month for month, x in app.temp_db.items()]
                    on_text: self.text

                DropdownMenu:
                    id: year
                    text: 'Select'
                    values: [f"{year}" for year in range(18, 46)]
                    on_text: self.text
                                                                            # Find now button
            RoundedGradientButton:
                text: "FIND NOW"
                font_size: 16
                size_hint: 0.25, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.15)}
<ResultPage>
    name: "result_page"
    MDScreen:
        md_bg_color: hex("#07074D")

    MDLabel:
        id: result_prefix_label
        text: "Congratulations!"
        color: hex("#ECE4F5")
        font_size: 20
        pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.7)}
        halign: "center"

    MDLabel:
        id: result_label
        color: hex("#ECE4F5")
        font_size: 40
        pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.6)}
        halign: "center"

    Button:
        background_normal: ""
        background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
        pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.3)}
        on_press: app.root.current = "landing_page"
        Image:
            source: "images/reload.png"
            center_x: self.parent.center_x
            center_y: self.parent.center_y
            size_hint_x: None
            height: 50
"""


class IntroPage(Screen):
    pass


class LandingPage(Screen):
    pass


class ResultPage(Screen):
    pass


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class BabyGenderFinder(MDApp):
    temp_db = {"January": 1, "February": 2, "March": 3, "April": 4, "May": 5}

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


    def DropdownBtnAnimation(self, wid):
        ani = Animation(angle=-90, duration=0.02)
        ani.start(wid)
                


BabyGenderFinder().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

                                                                    # Drop down button setting
<DropdownMenu@Spinner>
    dropdown_cls: Factory.CustomDropdown
    option_cls: Factory.DropdownOptions

    color: hex("#87828C")
    font_name: "fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    on_release: self.color = hex("ECE4F5") ; app.DropdownBtnAnimation(self.ids.dropdown_sign)

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: hex("#111140")
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [6]
        Color: 
            rgba: hex("#1F1F73")
        Line:
            width: 1.25
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100
            
    MDIconButton:
        id: dropdown_sign
        center_x: self.parent.center_x + 110
        center_y: self.parent.center_y
        angle: 0
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: self.angle
                axis: 0, 0, 1
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
        Image:            
            source: "images/dropdown.png"
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 20, 20

                                                                    # Drop down options setting
<DropdownOptions@SpinnerOption>
    color: hex("#ECE4F5")
    font_name: "fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
                                                                    # Drop down options separator setting
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: hex("#3D3D99")
        Line:
            width: 1
            points: self.x+10, self.y, self.width-10, self.y

<CustomDropdown@DropDown>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: hex("#1F1F73")
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [0, 0, 6, 6]
    max_height: 200

                                                                    # Gradient button settings
<RoundedGradientButton@Button>
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    font_name: "fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
    on_press: self.size_hint = self.size_hint_x/1.05, self.size_hint_y/1.05
    on_release: self.size_hint = self.size_hint_x*1.05, self.size_hint_y*1.05
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        RoundedRectangle:
            source: "button_bg.png"
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [self.size[1]/1.92]
```

I can make the button rotate down, but I can't seem to make the button go back to normal when dropdown options closes. I also want some actions done when I close Spinner widget (ex: If I clicked outside the dropdown options list when the list is open, I wanna trigger some actions)

I'm fairly new with kivy. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create dropdown animation, we can create close animation method just like `DropdownBtnAnimation` in **PY file**:

```
class BabyGenderFinder(MDApp):
    temp_db = {"January": 1, "February": 2, "March": 3, "April": 4, "May": 5}

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


    def DropdownBtnAnimation(self, wid):
        ani = Animation(angle=-90, duration=0.02)
        ani.start(wid)

    def dropdown_btn_close_animation(wid):
        ani = Animation(angle=0, duration=0.02)
        ani.start(wid)
```

And use `on_is_open` property in **kv**:

```
<DropdownMenu@Spinner>
    dropdown_cls: Factory.CustomDropdown
    option_cls: Factory.DropdownOptions

    color: hex("#87828C")
    font_name: "fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf"
    background_normal: ""
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0

    on_is_open: app.DropdownBtnAnimation(self.ids.dropdown_sign) if self.is_open == True else app.dropdown_btn_close_animation(self.ids.dropdown_sign)

    on_release: self.color = hex("ECE4F5")

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: hex("#111140")
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [6]
        Color: 
            rgba: hex("#1F1F73")
        Line:
            width: 1.25
            rounded_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, 6, 6, 6, 6, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `kv`, you can set the `angle` back to `0` when the `text` is changed on the `DropdownMenu`:

```
            DropdownMenu:
                id: month
                text: 'Select'
                values: [month for month, x in app.temp_db.items()]
                on_text: self.ids.dropdown_sign.angle=0
```

Or, you can eliminate the animation completely, and just set the angle of the icon to depend on whether the `DropdownMenu` is open:

```
MDIconButton:
    id: dropdown_sign
    center_x: self.parent.center_x + 110
    center_y: self.parent.center_y
    # angle: 0
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: 90 if root.is_open else 0  # adjusts angle of icon
            axis: 0, 0, 1
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
    Image:            
        source: "images/dropdown.png"
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 20, 20
```

Comment: Thanks fro the reply. It works but partially. It only goes back to normal when I select an item from the list, but if I closed it without selecting any of the items, it still remains facing down. I want the sign to go back to normal even if I closed it without selecting.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: But, is there a way to animate it?